# gsutil to list all files in a bucket that have been deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, ls, gsutil

How do you list all objects in a bucket that have been deleted when object versioning has been enabled? I'd like to use gsutil for this if possible.

Edit:
It seems like there is no built in tool to do this. Could there perhaps be a way to do it via some combination of gsutil and another bash tool?

When you have a large amount of files, listing all versions is too much information and obscures what one might be looking for: do I have any deleted files and should I permanently delete them or restore them.

Answer (score 5):

Running `gsutil help ls` shows that the `-a` flag will do this:

```
  -a          Includes non-current object versions / generations in the listing
              (only useful with a versioning-enabled bucket). If combined with
              -l option also prints metageneration for each listed object.
```

Note that this will show objects that were deleted while versioning was enabled. If an object is deleted when versioning is not turned on, it is permanently deleted.

Comment: I only want to see the deleted objects though. Not the current ones.

Answer (score 2):

When working with Object Versioning in GCP, the only [documented command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#list) to list archived objects, is the one listing both live and archived versions of an object and view their generation numbers, as aforementioned by @mhouglum.

gsutil ls -a gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

However, there are some additional flags, that can help you identify the archived objects. You can use the -L flag along with the -a flag. This command will give you the Archived Time for non-live versions of an object, but not for the live ones. 
Example:

Archived object

[image]

Live object

[image]

When an object has been permanently deleted, you can not list it anymore and the only way to view this operation deletion is by visiting the Logs.